# issues with newline strtok from a file

Tags: c

Alright so I have a file formatted like this:

7

1

2

3

4

5

And I have to read that in and make it a linked list while I add each new node to the head of the list. No biggie. Easy enough. My issue is that I'm running into a segfault. I'm working with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct{
        char number[10];
} numStruct;

typedef struct node{
        numStruct* numbers;
        struct node *next;
}Node;

void readNumbers(Node **head){
        FILE *inp = fopen("filelocation","r");
        char line[80];

        char *result;

        if(inp == NULL){
               printf("Oopsies doodles. We couldn't find this file!"); 
        }
         while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),inp)!=NULL){
                numStruct* numbers = malloc(sizeof(numStruct));
                result = strtok(line," "); 
                strcpy(numbers->number,result);
                Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                newNode->numbers = numbers;
                newNode->next = NULL;
                Node* oldHead = *head;
                *head = newNode;

                newNode -> next = oldHead;
                }
        fclose(inp);
        return;
}

void printNumbers(Node* head){
        Node* currentNode = head;
        while(currentNode !=NULL)
        {
                printf("%s",currentNode->numbers->number);
                currentNode = currentNode ->next;
        }
        return;
}

int main(void){
        Node *head = NULL;
        readNumbers(&head);
        printNumbers(head);
        return(0);
        }
```

My issue with strtok. I've tried \n and \r and all the combinations possible, but I'm still getting that error. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Which exact line of code does the seg fault occur on? Is it confirmed to be the `strtok` line? If not already doing so, a debugger can tell you that immediately. And why do you need to use `strtok` at all since there is one number per line in the input?

Comment: I guess I don't have to, but I wasn't sure what else I could use. I'm not actually sure what line is segfaults on, but I'm pretty sure it's that one since I ran into a similar issue earlier. @kaylum

Comment: Please use a debugger to confirm. That will save everyone (especially you) a lot of time.

Comment: Any recommendations? My professor is having us use vim, which doesn't have one to my knowledge.

Comment: Recommendation: in the "oopsie" block, be sure to exit after reporting that rather than fall through and use the NULL pointer after all.

Comment: vim is just an editor. Seems like you are using Linux. In that case a common debugger is gdb.

Comment: `numbers->number` is a fixed-size char array.

Comment: @SteveFriedl oopsies doodle, I was looking at the next `typedef`. There could be overflow though, it's unchecked.

Comment: Pro-tip: avoid strtok() Do your own parsing.

Comment: Using `number` or `numbers` for almost everything in sight is bound to be confusing.

Comment: Naming is not my forte. But yeah it's awful. 

What does it mean when something's unchecked? @WeatherVane

Comment: You copy a string into an array of size 10 without checking that the string is length 9 or less.

Comment: Ah gotcha. That makes some sense. Thanks! I'll run it through a debugger and hope for the best. Although it seems like I don't have any issues.

Comment: In serious C code you can't leave it open like that. You must either be sure there is no overflow or prevent it, with for example `strncpy` although that is trickier than at first sight. *"If count is less than or equal to the length of strSource, a null character is not appended automatically to the copied string."*

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but I do not have enough reputation :-(

Are you sure that your code is segfaulting? On my computer, your code just works fine. The only problem that it is leaking memory. You have called `malloc()` a lot of times but never a `free()`. Also remember to call `free()` against `result` variable, it points to memory allocated by `strtok()`.

My output:

```
5
4
3
2
1
7
```

Yes, the first line is empty.

Valgrind output below: ("a" is the binary, my user name is "user" and a is under my home folder)

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full -v ./a
==20308== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20308== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20308== Using Valgrind-3.14.0-353a3587bb-20181007X and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20308== Command: ./a
==20308== 
--20308-- Valgrind options:
--20308--    --leak-check=full
--20308--    -v
--20308-- Contents of /proc/version:
--20308--   Linux version 4.19.0-8-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26)
--20308-- 
--20308-- Arch and hwcaps: AMD64, LittleEndian, amd64-cx16-lzcnt-rdtscp-sse3-avx-avx2-bmi
--20308-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--20308-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind
--20308-- Reading syms from /home/user/a
--20308-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.28.so
--20308--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/f2/5dfd7b95be4ba386fd71080accae8c0732b711.debug ..
--20308--   .. build-id is valid
--20308-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
--20308--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/32/2e77af97f403c3d34ff09edf60b089e72ec889.debug ..
--20308--   .. build-id is valid
--20308--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--20308-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--20308-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/default.supp
==20308== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-20308-by-user-on-???
==20308== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-20308-by-user-on-???
==20308== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-20308-by-user-on-???
==20308== 
==20308== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==20308== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==20308== or are doing some strange experiment):
==20308==   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=20308 ...command...
==20308== 
==20308== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==20308==   /path/to/gdb ./a
==20308== and then give GDB the following command
==20308==   target remote | /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=20308
==20308== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==20308== 
--20308-- REDIR: 0x401e2f0 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strlen) redirected to 0x580c9ce2 (vgPlain_amd64_linux_REDIR_FOR_strlen)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x401e0d0 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:index) redirected to 0x580c9cfc (vgPlain_amd64_linux_REDIR_FOR_index)
--20308-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--20308--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/34/fbc4cdfbfce1bfc3d2e522a01a050bf724c930.debug ..
--20308--   .. build-id is valid
--20308-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
--20308--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/ca/bb7898ea982d936cbfadd70ae831c6eb63623f.debug ..
--20308--   .. build-id is valid
==20308== WARNING: new redirection conflicts with existing -- ignoring it
--20308--     old: 0x0401e2f0 (strlen              ) R-> (0000.0) 0x580c9ce2 vgPlain_amd64_linux_REDIR_FOR_strlen
--20308--     new: 0x0401e2f0 (strlen              ) R-> (2007.0) 0x04838d80 strlen
--20308-- REDIR: 0x401ab10 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strcmp) redirected to 0x4839e40 (strcmp)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x401e830 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:mempcpy) redirected to 0x483d860 (mempcpy)
--20308-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so
--20308--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/18/b9a9a8c523e5cfe5b5d946d605d09242f09798.debug ..
--20308--   .. build-id is valid
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e3f70 (libc.so.6:memmove) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e3160 (libc.so.6:strncpy) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e4250 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e2b70 (libc.so.6:strcat) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e3190 (libc.so.6:rindex) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e5890 (libc.so.6:rawmemchr) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48fe230 (libc.so.6:wmemchr) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48fdcd0 (libc.so.6:wcscmp) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e40e0 (libc.so.6:mempcpy) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e3f10 (libc.so.6:bcmp) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e3100 (libc.so.6:strncmp) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e2be0 (libc.so.6:strcmp) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e4040 (libc.so.6:memset) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48fdca0 (libc.so.6:wcschr) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e30a0 (libc.so.6:strnlen) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e2c70 (libc.so.6:strcspn) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e42a0 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e2c40 (libc.so.6:strcpy) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e43e0 (libc.so.6:memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48ff4d0 (libc.so.6:wcsnlen) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e31c0 (libc.so.6:strpbrk) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e2ba0 (libc.so.6:index) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e3070 (libc.so.6:strlen) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48ea280 (libc.so.6:memrchr) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e42f0 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp_l) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e3ee0 (libc.so.6:memchr) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48fddb0 (libc.so.6:wcslen) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e3460 (libc.so.6:strspn) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e4220 (libc.so.6:stpncpy) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e41f0 (libc.so.6:stpcpy) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e58c0 (libc.so.6:strchrnul) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e4340 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp_l) redirected to 0x482b1b0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x49b6fa0 (libc.so.6:__strrchr_avx2) redirected to 0x4838790 (rindex)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48df350 (libc.so.6:malloc) redirected to 0x4835710 (malloc)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48e3980 (libc.so.6:__GI_strstr) redirected to 0x483dac0 (__strstr_sse2)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x49b3000 (libc.so.6:__memchr_avx2) redirected to 0x4839ee0 (memchr)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x49b76b0 (libc.so.6:__memcpy_avx_unaligned_erms) redirected to 0x483c8a0 (memmove)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x49b2580 (libc.so.6:__strspn_sse42) redirected to 0x483dcc0 (strspn)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x49b22c0 (libc.so.6:__strcspn_sse42) redirected to 0x483dc00 (strcspn)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48f8100 (libc.so.6:__strcpy_sse2_unaligned) redirected to 0x4838db0 (strcpy)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x48df9a0 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4836940 (free)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x49b6db0 (libc.so.6:__strchrnul_avx2) redirected to 0x483d390 (strchrnul)
--20308-- REDIR: 0x49b7170 (libc.so.6:__strlen_avx2) redirected to 0x4838c60 (strlen)

--20308-- REDIR: 0x49b7690 (libc.so.6:__mempcpy_avx_unaligned_erms) redirected to 0x483d4a0 (mempcpy)
5
4
3
2
1
7
==20308== 
==20308== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20308==     in use at exit: 182 bytes in 14 blocks
==20308==   total heap usage: 17 allocs, 3 frees, 5,854 bytes allocated
==20308== 
==20308== Searching for pointers to 14 not-freed blocks
==20308== Checked 69,528 bytes
==20308== 
==20308== 182 (16 direct, 166 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
==20308==    at 0x483577F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==20308==    by 0x109220: readNumbers (a.c:28)
==20308==    by 0x1092F3: main (a.c:52)
==20308== 
==20308== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20308==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==20308==    indirectly lost: 166 bytes in 13 blocks
==20308==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20308==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20308==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20308== 
==20308== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==20308== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Well that's frustrating. It's definitely segfaulting on my end. 

"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: @sloppycanada That's too bad. If it keeps segfaulting, maybe follow the procedure in [this](https://jvns.ca/blog/2018/04/28/debugging-a-segfault-on-linux/) link.

Comment: @sloppycanada The only difference between the code you posted and my testing code is the filename field. Maybe check that if you do have `filelocation` file on your computer... and maybe check the $PATH$ variable of your program